# Trouble using if statements to add classes to elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a function where a button is clicked, a class is added called active. However, if the class also has either amd or intel in it, I want another class to be added as well. I can't seem to get my syntax correct though, could someone help me work out what I've done wrong here? Many thanks!

```
$(function() {    
    $(".button").click(function() {  
        if ( $(".button").hasClass("amd") ) {
            $(this).toggleClass("amdactive"),
                $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active'); }
        else if ( $(".button").hasClass("intel") ) {
            $(this).toggleClass("intelactive"),
                $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active'); }
        else $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');    
  });
});
```

I've actually fixed the code now, but for some reason the intelactive class is applied to all .buttons, not just ones that contain amd. Any reason why?

Final code, thanks for the help

```
$(function() {    
$(".button").click(function() {  
    if ( $(this).hasClass("amd") ) {
        $(this).toggleClass("amdactive"),
        $(".intel").removeClass("intelactive"),
        $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active'); }
    else if ( $(this).hasClass("intel") ) {
        $(this).toggleClass("intelactive"),
        $(".amd").removeClass("amdactive"),
        $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active'); }
    else {$(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');};    
  });
});
```

Comment: edited portion works now? and what diffrence it produces @Beau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have syntax errors you are placing round brackets instead od curly brackets in if/else blocks

Secondly you should check with "this" in has class. you are checking for all buttons

```
$(function() {    
$(".button").click(function() {  
    if ( $(this).hasClass("amd") ) {
        $(this).addClass("amdactive"),
        $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active'); }
    else if ( $(this).hasClass("intel") ) {
        $(this).addClass("intelactive"),
        $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active'); }
    else {$(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');};    
  });
});
```

Also,  you are not removing amdactive classes from other buttons on click so if all clicked one time all have amdactive class

So you need to do something like

```
$(this).addClass("intelactive");
 $(".button").not($(this)).removeClass("intelactive");
```

Comment: Thanks! I realised that and fixed it. It's still not working however and applys the amdactive class to any .button, not just the ones containing the class amd

Comment: have you fixed this too "you should check with "this" in has class. you are checking for all buttons"?

Comment: I appreciate what you've come up with there. does the syntax allow for me to do something along the lines of $(this).addClass("amdactive").$('.amd').removeClass("amdactive"); ??

Stupid question, fixed it! I thank you so much!!

Comment: edited, replace .button with .amd in last line of my asnwer that has removeClass

Comment: I'll show you my final code in the original post, thanks for your help

Comment: my pleasure, just another thing do you really want .amd buttons from which .amdactive class is to be removed? as in this else block button those which dont have amd will be there? i mean its in if block that have "amd" class